# action callback, for action dispatched as reported by hook sniffer, not called

Tags: plugin-development, actions

I installed the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/hook-sniffer/.

```
Action Event Firing Order:

Array
(
  [muplugins_loaded] => 1
  ...
  [the_post] => 3
  ...
)
...
```

yet

```
function plugin_the_post() {
  customErrLog('plugin_the_post');
}

function pluginActivate() {
  customErrLog('pluginActivate');
  add_action('the_post', 'plugin_the_post');
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'pluginActivate');
```

I get `pluginActivate` in my debug log but `plugin_the_post` never happens.

I'm not actually interested in `the_post` but there have been several action hooks that others seem to use well, and yet I get nothing...

can an action hook callback prevent other callbacks from getting called...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Close voted as you rely on a plugin which might be the cause of the problem and therefor you are off-topic. Get rid of the plugin, and just hook on 'the_post' if that is what you want to do. 'the_post' should almost always be called unless you are doing things in the admin side of things at which point it will depend on what exactly are you doing.

Comment: I don't think that `the_post` action hook is available during plugin activation.

Comment: "deleted" the plugin, and still all I get is activation and `init` callbacks

Comment: @cybmeta I don't care if `the_post` is used during plugin activation, my problem is that `plugin_the_post` is *never* called, not during general site usage, not during user account registration.  even `add_action('login_form_login', 'plugin_login_form_login')` results in nothing ever happening.

Comment: @cybmeta this is a fresh install of wordpress I only installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/ and the hook sniffer... as of right now only 'theme-my-login' is installed and active (except the default plugins e.g. akismet, hello dolly...)

Comment: @user3338098, from your code you trigger 'the_post' only on plugin activation. You need the hook to be "defined" in some other place, most likely global context for this text, in practice usually on the init hook for most hooks, but this may depend on what exactly do you want to do.

Comment: @mark-kaplun I thought that `add_action` didn't trigger/dispatch the hook but just registered a call back function to be 'called back' latter after the core code of wordpress called `do_action` which, by my understanding, should result in my 'call back' `plugin_the_post` getting called.

Comment: yes, just took shortcuts with my english ;) the thing is that plugin activation happens only once when the plugin is being activated and once that execution is done for the next page view you need to register all the hooks again.

Comment: That is exactly what I said (or what I wanted to mean): `the_post` action is not active during plugin activation and your code add the callback for this action only on plugin activation.

Comment: @mark-kaplun that was it, thank you both for your time.